# Twig & Smarty: object from JSON file

Tags: json, smarty, twig

I'm learning both Twig and Smarty and I didn't find an answer for my question for both of them. The question is: is there some built-in way to read variable's value from separate JSON file? I'll use Twig for my examples. OK, this is regular Twig variable definition:

```
{% set vars = {"foo" : "bar"} %}
```

Now let's assume that we have a JSON file at `/var/www/html/website.com/vars.json` that contains:

```
{
    "foo" : "bar"
}
```

And now I want to initialize my `vars` with this object, but read it from file instead of definition in the template, something like that:

```
{% set vars = *some_magic* "/var/www/html/website.com/vars.json" %}
```

Or, the better example, to use object from the file as include parameter:

```
{% include "menu.html" with *some_magic* "/var/www/html/website.com/menu.json" only %}
```

So, is there some build-in way, or, at least, what is the best way to implement it as an extenstion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own custom twig function e.g. loadFromJsonFile(filename) and use it like {% set data = loadFromJsonFile('/var/www/html/website.com/menu.json') %}

Here is

- [how to extend twig in symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)
- [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html)

Comment: What is the best way, a function or a filter? I.e. like this: {% set data = '/var/www/html/website.com/menu.json' | json %}

Comment: IMHO you should use filters to modify data but in your situation you load data. So twig function is preferable

Comment: Okay, looks like a solution has been found :)